# image not uploaded after calling upload function in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nude.js

I'm working on an image upload form which will validate if the uploaded picture contain nudity with the help of [nudejs](https://github.com/pa7/nude.js) script.
If the image doesn't contain nudity it will be uploaded.
The upload and check nudity function are working great, but the problem is that i didn't find a way to link these 2 methods since the return of the check nudity function "onImageClick()" come `'undefined'` so i can't check if its true or false in order to call the upload function via `$.ajax`.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //return onImageClick('previewing'); //previewing is the id of the image in my html file
        //if(onImageClick('previewing')) return;
        var rn = onImageClick('previewing');
        console.log("rn: "+rn); //always get undefined 
        $("#message").empty();
        $('#loading').show();

        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax_php_file.php",
          type: "POST",            
          data: new FormData(this),
          contentType: false,      
          cache: false,            
          processData:false,       
          success: function(data) {
             $('#loading').hide();
             $("#message").html(data);
          }
      });
}));

// Function to preview image after validation
$(function() {
    $("#file").change(function() {
        $("#message").empty(); // To remove the previous error message
        var file = this.files[0];
        var imagefile = file.type;
        var match = ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
        if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2]))) {
           $('#previewing').attr('src','no-preview.png');
           $("#message").html("<p id='error'>Please Select A valid Image File</p>"+"<h4>Note</h4>"+"<span id='error_message'>Only jpeg, jpg and png Images type allowed</span>");
           return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
         }
     });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $("#file").css("color","green");
    $('#image_preview').css("display", "block");
    $('#previewing').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $('#previewing').attr('width', '250px');
    $('#previewing').attr('height', '230px');
};
//check nudity function
function onImageClick(node) {
    nude.load(node);
    // Scan it
    nude.scan(function(result){ 
        console.log(result ? "Nudity found in " + node + "!" : "Not nude");
                console.log("returned value is:",result);
                return result;
    });
}
});
```

**EDIT: I edit the code based on @Amir answer where he mention an important point i didn't notice before.** 
Now i can fire the upload function when there is no nudity, but the image didn't uploaded even the success function in ajax call is fired:

```
    success: function(data)   
    {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $("#message").html(data);
    }
```

This is the new code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
//call check nudity function
onImageClick('previewing');
//check nudity function
function onImageClick(node) {
    nude.load(node);
    // Scan it
    nude.scan(function(result){ 
        console.log(result ? "Nudity found in " + node + "!" : "Not nude");
                console.log("returned value is:",result);
                if(result){
                    alert("conatain nudity!!");
                }
      else{
            $("#message").empty();
            $('#loading').show();
                $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_php_file.php", 
            type: "POST",             
            data: new FormData(this), 
            contentType: false,       
            cache: false,             
            processData:false,        
            success: function(data)   
            {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $("#message").html(data);
            }
                });
              }
    });
};

}));

// Function to preview image after validation
$(function() {
$("#file").change(function() {
$("#message").empty(); // To remove the previous error message
var file = this.files[0];
var imagefile = file.type;
var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2])))
{
$('#previewing').attr('src','no-preview.png');
$("#message").html("<p id='error'>Please Select A valid Image File</p>"+"<h4>Note</h4>"+"<span id='error_message'>Only jpeg, jpg and png Images type allowed</span>");
return false;
}
else
{
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}
});
});
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
$("#file").css("color","green");
$('#image_preview').css("display", "block");
$('#previewing').attr('src', e.target.result);
$('#previewing').attr('width', '250px');
$('#previewing').attr('height', '230px');
};

});
```

Comment: It's funny, I thought you want to say _nodejs_, but you are right

Comment: yes nude.js :) if you have any idea about how to solve this problem i will be thankful :)

Comment: Whatever the outcome of this, please bear in mind that you're doing this validation on the browser. It is always possible for a malicious user to circumvent browser-side validation. If you need to be bulletproof on this, then you need to also do your validation on the server as well, after the image has been uploaded.

Comment: @Spudley  thanks for this info, how can i check this in server side too? you mean moderate function or an automatic script too?

Comment: It could be either moderated or automatic, depending on your needs. I don't know of any automated tools for your task on the server side, but I'm sure they must exist.

Comment: @Spudley i search for an automated back-end script for this too, but i couldn't find any. it will helpful if anyone suggest one for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this, the problem was with FormData, it was returning:
**TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.** That is for some reason didn't appear in chrome console but it does in Firefox.
So i added this line of code in the else statement(in case nudity not found):

```
var form = $('form').get(0);
```

this code returns a jQuery object(`$('form')`) and pass a HTML element to FormData (`get(0)`).
Then in ajax request: `data: new FormData(form),`
Hope that this solution help other people.

Answer (score 2):

nude.scan is async so you should pass a callback.
something like:

```
nude.scan(function (result) { /* your logic according to the result */ })
```

Comment: thank you, i tried this code based on your answer, it's now checking if image contain nudity or not but in case the image contain nudity it didn't upload the image: https://jsfiddle.net/f1659mj5/ even the function is called since the `$('#loading').hide();` is alerted.

Comment: I can see you are using 'this' - new FormData(this), so you probably should bind the relevant context: nude.scan(function (result){/*your code*/}.bind(this))

Comment: this doesn't change anything too. here is a screenshot from console: http://imgur.com/UrafftB

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of the request (network tab)?

Comment: Thanks @Amir i found where the problem is and solve it.